# Troubles with react

Tags: reactjs

I Have some trouble. There are two classes: `List` and `Item`:

```js
var React = require('react'),
var List = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   items: []
  }
 },
 handleItemChange: function(index, itemData) {
  //..do something with items[index]
 },
 renderItems: function() {
  return items.map(function(item, i) {
   return (
    <Item
     {...item}
     onChange={this.handleItemChange.bind(this, i)}
    />
   );
  });
 },
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>
  );
 }
});
var Item = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <p>Name: <input
    type="text"
    defaultValue={this.props.name}
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
   /></p>
   <p>Age: <input
    type="text"
    defaultValue={this.props.age}
    onChange={this.props.onChange}
   /></p>
  );
 }
});
```

I want to append `itemData` to `handleItemChange` arguments, but i don't want to clean arguments that binded before (something like `onChange={this.props.onChange.bind(<skip context>, <skip index>, {some item data...})}`). What i must do?

Answer (score 0):

### Pass the relevant data as `props`

Something like this, perhaps? We pass the `itemData` and `index` as **props** to the child component `Item` in the map function. We then return those props to the parent `List` from the method `returnData` on the child component.

```
var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
          // added example items for demonstration
          items: [
            {name: 'Tom', age: 21},
            {name: 'Bill', age: 44}
          ]
      }
  },
  handleItemChange: function(index, itemData) {
      console.log(index, itemData);
  },
  renderItems: function() {
      // used to get the handleItemChange method inside the map function
      var listComponent = this;

      return this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
          return (
              <Item
                  {...item}
                  // pass the data and index to the item component
                  // we can then return them later
                  itemData={item}
                  index={i}
                  onChange={listComponent.handleItemChange}
                  // Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
                  key={i}
              />
          );
      });
  },
  render: function() {
      return (
          <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>
      );
  }
});
var Item = React.createClass({
  returnData: function() {
    // pass the props to the onChange function
    this.props.onChange(this.props.index, this.props.itemData);
  },
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Name: <input
              type="text"
              defaultValue={this.props.name}
              onChange={this.returnData}
          /></p>
          <p>Age: <input
              type="text"
              defaultValue={this.props.age}
              onChange={this.returnData}
          /></p>
        </div>
      );
  }
});
```